# Selenium ide pass a variable to a payload

Tags: selenium-ide

I want to pass a variable value generated in previous testcase to next testcase where I am running a passing a variable to the payload like below, but it only see it as a string not a value, any idea. Using XMLHTTP to run the payload so ideally it should substitute with the value of the variable generate din the previous script , tried a few more ways but could not resolve

```
"payload": [{"typeOfCustomer": "${id}","samplingProgramCode": 1}]
```

When I run it just echo `${id}` not the actually value.